# How can i get the print statements within the script task of activiti

Tags: activiti

I am using activiti latest version(5.21.0) and trying to print some data inside the script task and for script task i'm using 'javascript'as language.When i'm using console.log to print data,i'm getting the following error.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined in <eval> at line number 2, message problem evaluating script: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined in <eval> at line number 2
```

[Sample Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crfdf.jpg)

[script task code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9KxF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

"console" is a global that usually available in web browsers but not in the Activitips provided environment hence the error you´re seeing

In order to print something, you can use the following (lengthy) statement:

java.lang.System.out.println("HELLO");

Answer (score 0):

If you are in  Groovy Script task you simply need to use:out.print() or out.println()

Comment: Can we debug script task?